# Is it true that any open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ has at most countably many connected components?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I want to understand the open connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am not able to think of any open set which has more than countable connected components. Is this true or is there any counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is true. For each open component of open set we can take the point that has rational coordinates belongs to this open component. Corresponding the open component and this rational number then you get the function from set of open components of given open set to countable set, so there is at most countably open components.

Comment: (This argument has already been given twice, three minutes ago.)

Comment: @Pedrotamaroff It is well known method. Because I use the mobile, writing speed for answer is too slow.

Comment: @tetori: when I see that someone posted an essentially identical answer before me and I can't really expand it (because I don't feel like it, if for no other reason), I just delete mine.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is true.

This is because components of an open set are disjoint, open sets and ${\bf R}^n$ is separable (the rational tuples are dense).

Answer (score 4):

An open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ can have at most countably many connected components. This is due to the fact that in each such component it is always possible to find a point $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where all $x_i$'s are rational. And as all such points are countably many, then the components are at most countably many.

Comment: (This argument has already been given twice, three minutes ago.)

Comment: It took me more than 3 minutes to write it!

Comment: Fair enough. Just saying there is no need for four question all containing the same answer.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: when I see that someone posted an essentially identical answer before me and I can't really expand it (because I don't feel like it, if for no other reason), I just delete mine.

Answer (score 3):

It is true. Every open ball in $\Bbb R ^2$ contains a pair of rational numbers. Thus there can't be more than countably many disconnected open sets.

Comment: You mean $\Bbb R^n$?